# Flutter widget is not a subtype

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a base state for my flutter file. I created a base structure but I can't use it on my page, I get this error.

**Error**

type '(BuildContext, SplashViewModel) =>
Widget' is not a subtype of type
'(BuildContext, dynamic) => Widget'
See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/
errors

**SplashView**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:motiontraq/core/base/state/base_state.dart';
import 'package:motiontraq/core/base/view/base_widget.dart';
import 'package:motiontraq/view/authentication/splash/splash_view_model.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends BaseState<SplashScreen> {
  SplashViewModel viewModel = SplashViewModel();

  // onModelReady işlevini dynamic türünde tanımla
  void onModelReady(dynamic model) {
    viewModel =
        model as SplashViewModel; // Modeli SplashViewModel olarak dönüştür
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseView<SplashViewModel>(
      viewModel: viewModel,
      onModelReady: onModelReady, // onModelReady işlevini atayın
      onPageBuilder: (context, value) => scaffoldBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget scaffoldBody() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text(viewModel.deneme)),
    );
  }
}
```

**BaseWidget**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Sonradan Gerekebilir diye BaseView oluşturuldu ve içi boş bırakıldı.

class BaseView<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  const BaseView({
    required this.viewModel,
    required this.onPageBuilder,
    super.key,
    this.onModelReady,
    this.onDispose,
  });
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T value) onPageBuilder;
  final T viewModel;
  final void Function(T model)? onModelReady;
  final VoidCallback? onDispose;

  @override
  State<BaseView> createState() => _BaseViewState();
}

class _BaseViewState extends State<BaseView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.onModelReady?.call(widget.viewModel);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    widget.onDispose?.call();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.onPageBuilder(context, widget.viewModel);
  }
}
```

**SplashViewModel**

```
    class SplashViewModel {
  String deneme = "deneme";
}
```

**BaseState**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

abstract class BaseState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State<T> {
  ThemeData get currentTheme => Theme.of(context);

  double dynamicHeight(double value) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * value;
  double dynamicWidth(double value) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * value;
  double screenWidth() => MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  double screenHeight() => MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
}
```

Comment: Where is defined `BaseState`? I only see `_BaseViewState`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why it needs to be like this but changing this line

```
  onPageBuilder: (context, value) => scaffoldBody(),
```

to

```
  onPageBuilder: (context, dynamic value) => scaffoldBody(),
```

seems to solve the issue, but admittedly that's far from ideal if you actually want to use the value as the indicated type. I see for `onModelReady` you needed to do the same actually